# Working with RegEx, but I dont know how to approach my issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

`^\d{1,12}$|(?=^.{1,15}$)^\d+\.\d{1,2}$`

This is the expression I currently have.

I want the max limit to be 100 000 000 000 with optional two decimals max, but if the user only adds 1 decimal, they can bump the value to 100 000 000 0001.1 if they want to.

How can I approach this issue? and is there any way to make 100 000 000 000 the max value? (Not 999 999 999 999)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem for a regex. Can you validate another way?

Comment: I am using the Joi validation package, and was using the number with precision etc. But I ran into some major issues with this

Comment: `reactjs` is added as one of your tags. If this is related to an input field, you might want to update the question to include some of that code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match numbers from `0` to `99999999999` with any two digits in the decimal part or `100000000000` with only zeros in the decimal part:

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,11})(?:\.\d{1,2})?|10{11}(?:\.00?)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qYpmpe/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,11})` - `0` to `99999999999` number
  - `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` char and then one or two digits
  - `|` - or
  - `10{11}(?:\.00?)?`  - `1` and then 11 zeros optionally followed with `.` and one or two zeros
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{1,12}$|(?=^.{1,15}$)^\d{1,12}\.\d{1,2}$
```

It seems the problem is the plus sign in the second part of the regex

Answer (score 0):

For the part without the decimal I tried this :

> ^\d{1,11}$|^100000000000$|(?=^.{1,15}$)^\d+.\d{1,2}$

// works :
100000000000

// doesn't work :
999999999999

I don't know for the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^\d{1,12}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/FcRDII/1

for the max value being 100 000 000 000, i would not validate that with regex, but if you have no other options this might work

```
^(?:1[0]{11}|\d{1,11})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/V6b1Fv/1